# I'm working with ListFragment but I'm having some problems with LoaderManager

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-loadermanager

I'm making a music player and I'm just trying to display artist names using ListFragment. Here is the code:

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AlbumsFragment extends ListFragment implements
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks < Cursor > {

    AlbumsAdapter mAdapter;

    @
    Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_list, container, false);
        return myFragmentView;
    }


    @
    Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new AlbumsAdapter(getActivity(), null);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }


    static final String[] ALBUM_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = {
        MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM
    };



    public Loader < Cursor > onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String select = null;
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ALBUM_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, null);
    }



    public void onLoadFinished(Loader < Cursor > loader, Cursor data) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }



    public void onLoaderReset(Loader < Cursor > loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

I get an error saying:
The method initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks) in the type LoaderManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, null, AlbumsFragment)

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this in your imports ?

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
```

It means you are using Support version of LoaderManager.

So you should replace

```
 getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

With

```
 getSupportLoadManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Comment: I tried that but it shows up an error saying "The method getSupportLoaderManager() is undefined for the type AlbumsFragment"

Answer (score 0):

You should also be using

```
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
```

as currently you are using the standard ListFragment as opposed to the support one.